# Spark: JavaRDD<Tuple2> to JavaPairRDD<>

Tags: java, mapreduce, apache-spark

I have a `JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, String>>` and need to transform it to `JavaPairRDD<String, String>`. Currently I am doing it by simply writing map function that just returns the input tuple as is. But I wonder if there is a better way?

Comment: Ok, so there is no better way in Java, right?

Comment: `new JavaPairRDD(javaRdd)` ?

Comment: Might be.. I also finally found PairJavaRDD.fromJavaRDD(rdd)

Comment: if you are the one constructing the `JavaRDD<Tuple2<String,String>>` e.g., from a map transformation of a  JavaPairRDD, you could instead call mapToPair and avoid having a JavaRDD in the first place.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

JavaPairRDD.fromJavaRDD(rdd) is one of solutions

Comment: JavaRDD<SmartBuildingNew> buildingRDD = jsc.sparkContext().parallelize(listSmartBuilding); I want to iterate over this JavaRDD, could you help me. SmartBuildingNew is a POJO class.jsc is the JavaStreamingContext object

Answer (score 4):

For reverse conversion, this seems to work:

```
JavaRDD.fromRDD(JavaPairRDD.toRDD(rdd), rdd.classTag());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this example:

```
JavaRDD<Tuple2<Integer, String>> mutate = mutateFunction(rdd_world); //goes to a method that generates the RDD with a Tuple2 from a rdd_world RDD
JavaPairRDD<Integer,  String> pairs = JavaPairRDD.fromJavaRDD(mutate);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this to transform JavaRDD into JavaPairRDD. For me It is working perfectly.

```
JavaRDD<Sensor> sensorRdd = lines.map(new SensorData()).cache();
// transform data into javaPairRdd
JavaPairRDD<Integer, Sensor> deviceRdd = sensorRdd.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Sensor, Integer, Sensor>() {   
    public Tuple2<Integer, Sensor> call(Sensor sensor) throws Exception {
        Tuple2<Integer, Sensor>  tuple = new Tuple2<Integer, Sensor>(Integer.parseInt(sensor.getsId().trim()), sensor);
        return tuple;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can call `mapToPair(..)` on your instance of `org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD`.