# How to parallelize a list of key value pairs to JavaPairRDD in Apache spark Java API?

Tags: apache-spark, java

I have List of Key,value pairs such as List((A,1),(B,2),(C,3)) in heap memory. How can I parallelize this list to create a JavaPairRDD?
In scala :
   val pairs = sc.parallelize(List((A,1),(B,2),(C,3)).
Likewise, Is there any way with java API?

Comment: Did it happen that you RFTM ?

Comment: I referred the manual. I know how to do it with scala and python. is there any way doing it with java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. First store the List of tuples in JavaRDD and then convert it to JavaPairRDD.

```
    List<Tuple2> data =  Arrays.asList(new Tuple2("panda", 0),new Tuple2("panda", 1));
    JavaRDD rdd = sc.parallelize(data);
    JavaPairRDD pairRdd = JavaPairRDD.fromJavaRDD(rdd);
```

Have a look at this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27024169/spark-javarddtuple2-to-javapairrdd)

Answer (score 1):

I can see this one working for me

```
sc.parallelizePairs(Arrays.asList(new Tuple2("123","123")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Parallelized collections are created by calling JavaSparkContext’s parallelize method on an existing Collection in your driver program. The elements of the collection are copied to form a distributed dataset that can be operated on in parallel.

```
List data = ......;
JavaRDD rdd = sc.parallelize(data);
```

Comment: By using the above lines you can only store the elements not the key value pairs. And also I am trying to create JavaPairRDD not JavaRDD

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: @SandeepVeerlapati if type of your list is tuple, I think spark will create pairedRDD

Comment: @shekar what you are saying is correct in case of scala api.

Answer (score 0):

```
Convert Tuple into List with below code snippet.
Tuple2<Sensor, Integer> tuple = new Tuple2<Sensor, Integer>(arg0._2, 1);
                List<Tuple2<Sensor, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<Tuple2<Sensor, Integer>>();
                list.add(tuple);
```